# Stuck with building an object based on date from two separate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, date, object

So basically, I have an array of date between a range:

```
['2019-01-01, '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03'...'2019-01-30'];
```

And an array of objects containing data for the dates in the above range:

```
[{date: '2019-01-01', count: 2'}, {date: '2019-01-05', count: 4'}...{date: '2019-01-25', count: 3}]
```

Note, if there is no count at a particular date between those ranges in the first array, it does not appear in the second array at all. So, if there were 30 dates in the first array, there may only be 25 dates in the second array.

Ultimately, I would like to build an array of object in the form:

```
[
 { date: '2019-01-01',
   count: 2
 },
 {
   date: '2019-01-02',
   count: 0
 },
];
```

So, the array will contain an object for each date in the range (from first array), and will get the count (from the second array). If the date is not in the second array, then it will set the count as 0 in the array of objects.

I'm having a really hard time trying to figure out how to do this. I've tried various loops but am getting nowhere. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The "dates" are just strings that you can compare using `==`. What have you tried?

Comment: Loop the first array, find the matching element in the second array (maybe use `find`) then build an object and put it in a third array. Try that and see how you get on. If you don't know how to do these things, do some reasearch

Comment: Please add code you've tried to the question. Ideally a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array with same value number as `range`.

For each value of `range`, check in `counts` if there is already an existing count.

If there's one, return it. If there's none, return a new "0 count".

Code version:

```js
const range = [
    '2019-01-01',
    '2019-01-02',
    '2019-01-03', 
    '2019-01-04',
    '2019-01-05',
    '2019-01-06',
    '2019-01-07',
];

const counts = [
    {date: '2019-01-01', count: 2}, 
    {date: '2019-01-05', count: 4}, 
    {date: '2019-01-07', count: 3},
];

const result = range.map(date =>
  counts.find(element => element.date === date) || { date, count: 0 });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This helped build my solution (what I asked is actually just a small part of a bigger problem), thank you!